# Weird Message in Orbot logs?

Tags: anonymity, security, directory

I see something like the following line in log:

> WARN: Recived 404 Status Code "Not Found" from server [IP:Port] while fetching "/tor/keys/fp/[hash refrence here]"

Two very intresting things come up on investigation:

1. The involved IP is not a Tor node according to atlas, and i know it isn't a bridge node.
2. To my understanding Tor isn't supposed to be an HTTP server, but rather a SOCKS server, so it begs me to reason why tor would be making an HTTP request for some sort of key in the first place.

Really makes me wonder whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

Tor uses the [Directory Protocol](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt) to download information about the network. A description for the location `/tor/keys/fp/[hash refrence here]` can be found at [line 3319 of that specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n3319):

```
   The key certificate for an authority whose authority identity fingerprint
   is <F> should be available at:
      http://<hostname>/tor/keys/fp/<F>.z
```

As you can see this information is available via HTTP. It can be found at the directory authorities. Atlas has a [list of them](https://atlas.torproject.org/#search/flag:authority).

Besides directory authorities also Tor relays can offer directory information. It might be the case that this specific relay was shut down while your Tor client wanted to download the information. You can check [Exonerator](https://exonerator.torproject.org/) to see if it was a Tor relay.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowledge of the fingerprint I've no idea exactly what it might have been but it *could* be a relay that's no longer part of the consensus.

All the directory information uploads and downloads is done over HTTP, see: [dir-spec.txt:178](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n178)

So it may be your client tried to fetch information about a relay that it previously knew about but is no longer a relay. You may be able to find historic reference to the fingerprint in the [CollecTor](https://collector.torproject.org/) archives.